# How to set seeds when using parallel package in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am currently using the `parallel` package in R and I am trying to make by work reproducible by setting seeds.

However, if you set the seed before creating the cluster and performing the tasks you want in parallel, for some reason, it doesn't make it reproducible. I think I need to set the seed for each core when I make the cluster.

I have made a small example here to illustrate my problem:

```
library(parallel)

# function to generate 2 uniform random numbers
runif_parallel <- function() {
  # make cluster of two cores
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)

  # sample uniform random numbers
  samples <- parallel::parLapplyLB(cl, X = 1:2, fun = function(i) runif(1))

  # close cluster
  parallel::stopCluster(cl)

  return(unlist(samples))
}

set.seed(41)
test1 <- runif_parallel()

set.seed(41)
test2 <- runif_parallel()

# they should be the same since they have the same seed
identical(test1, test2)
```

In this example, the `test1` and `test2` should be the same, as they have the same seed, but they return different results.

Can I get some help with where I'm going wrong please?

Note that I've written this example the way I have to mimic how I'm using it right now - there are probably cleaner ways to generate two random uniform numbers in parallel.

Comment: set seed inside function(i)

Answer (score 4):

You need to run `set.seed` within each job.
Here is a reproducable random generation:

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)

# sample uniform random numbers
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, set.seed(41));

samples <- parallel::parLapplyLB(cl, X = 1:2, fun = function(i){set.seed(i);runif(1)})
samples

# [[1]]
# [1] 0.2655087
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.1848823

samples <- parallel::parLapplyLB(cl, X = 1:2, fun = function(i){set.seed(i);runif(1)})
samples

# [[1]]
# [1] 0.2655087
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.1848823

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: is there a way that you can just set a seed for all cores? I actually do many functions  before closing the cluster, so I guess my example wasnt totally reproducing my problem

Comment: You can set the same random seed in each job with this line: `parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, set.seed(41))`

Comment: making them the same seed just essentially replicates the random number though

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to have different, but reproducable random number generation.

Comment: they produce the same result in this code because of the `set.seed(i)` part within the function and the `set.seed(41)` part doesn't affect the randomisation here. i think i need a solution where you set a different seed for each core

Comment: WARNING: Getting statistical sound random number generation in parallel processing takes a lot of care and it's important to get it correct, especially if you do statistical analysis.  It's easy to get something working (like proposed here) but that doesn't mean it's the way you want to do it.  You want to use something like L'Ecuyer's RNGs, cf. ?parallel::RNGstreams.  If you use `foreach()`, you can use doRNG for this.  The `future.apply::future_lapply(..., future.seed=TRUE)` will also do it for you.

Comment: @HenrikB thanks! I found this resource too which helps: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_6245/slides/chapter4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In case it might be of help, one quick way to set separate seeds for each core

```
# Set number of cores, here to n-1
nCores <- parallel::detectCores()-1

# Parallelization, n-1 cores
parallel::setDefaultCluster(cl = (cl <- parallel::makeCluster(nCores)))

thisSeed <- 1
# Set different seeds in each cluster; here set to 1 for the cluster, 2 for the second, etc. 
# Do something in each cluster
(parRes <- do.call(c, parallel::clusterApply(x = 1:nCores+thisSeed-1, fun = function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  runif(1)
  })))

# Stop cluster
stopCluster(cl = cl)

# Same thing, not in parallel
singleRes <- do.call(c, lapply(1:nCores+thisSeed-1, function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  runif(1)
}))

# Verify that the results are the same
all(parRes == singleRes)
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `parallel::clusterSetRNGStream()`.

```
library(parallel)

CL <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)


clusterSetRNGStream(CL, 42)  ## set seed

t(parSapply(CL, 1:3, \(i) runif(1)))
#           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 0.1738456 0.5004388 0.127589


clusterSetRNGStream(CL, 42)  ## set same seed again

t(parSapply(CL, 1:3, \(i) runif(1)))
#           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 0.1738456 0.5004388 0.127589


stopCluster(CL)
```