# Set seed Does Not work on my Windows as I Copied from Different Examples Using R

Tags: r, reproducible-research

I searched and got the below example as a way of setting seed for `loop` from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358098/how-to-set-seed-for-random-simulations-with-foreach-and-domc-packages)

```
## Load packages and prepare multicore process
library(forecast)
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
n_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())
set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
a <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}
b <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}
identical(a,b)
```

I got the result to be `FALSE`

I also tried the answer I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236344/how-do-i-set-seed-for-simulation-in-r-to-attain-reproducibility/64236620#64236620) which is not reproducible as the answer claim. I beginning to suspect if I am missing out something which I do not know.

I am on Windows, I need help as regards why I am not getting what others are getting with the same `R` code.

Comment: If the result wasn't `FALSE` something would be seriously wrong. The RNG produces a sequence of random numbers. `set.seed` starts the sequence at a specific "state" (ensuring you always get the same sequence) but it is still a sequence.

Comment: @Roland There’s an answer in the linked thread which claims this works. But yeah, this *shouldn’t* work.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58631543/6574038

Answer (score 3):

You just need to re-set the seed before the second `rnorm()` call:

```r
library(forecast)
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
n_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())
set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
a <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}
set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
b <- foreach(i=1:2,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {rnorm(5)}
identical(a,b)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @DanielJames OK; in that case, can you edit your question to include a [mcve]? Since I didn't know what code you used to set up your parallelism, I just used the approach in the question you linked to

Comment: @DanielJames See my edit; the approach of simply re-setting the seed still works with your posted code

Comment: I commend your effort and patience, I still get `FALSE` as an answer even with your edited example.

Comment: @DanielJames crazy... I guess it really is a Windows issue. I noticed that you weren't re-setting the seed in between `rnorm()` calls, which would cause it to be `FALSE` on **any** system, so I thought that might be what was causing your issue... sorry this didn't solve it for you (don't have a Windows system to test on)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222654/discussion-between-daniel-james-and-duckmayr).

Comment: Different parallelization mechanisms are used on *nix and windows systems. If you want reproducible random numbers with parallelization, use `doRNG`.